# SQL: INNER JOIN for two levels of aggregation

Tags: sql, group-by, inner-join

My question is about a SQL query that returns a course list (see image).

Instead of the `class_id`, I would like to print the name of the class. The class name is stored in table `classes`. I already tried it with `INNER JOIN`, but unfortunately I haven't found a solution yet.

[image: See image]

```
select 
    group_concat(ids) as ids,
    group_concat(class_id) as class_ids,
    teacher, name, weekday_hours
from
    (select 
         l.class_id, l.teacher_id, l.name,
         group_concat(l.weekday, ':', l.hour order by l.weekday, l.hour) as weekday_hours,
         group_concat(l.id order by l.id) as ids
     from 
         lessons l
     group by 
         l.class_id, l.teacher_id, l.name) l
group by 
    teacher, name, weekday_hours;
```

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.  See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 0):

You want to `join` in the subquery and then process the `name` just as you would the `class_id`:

```
select group_concat(ids) as ids,
       group_concat(class_name) as class_names,
       teacher, name, weekday_hours
from (select l.class_id, c.name as class_name,
             l.teacher_id, l.name,
             group_concat(l.weekday, ':', l.hour order by l.weekday, l.hour) as weekday_hours,
             group_concat(l.id order by l.id) as ids
      from lessons l join
           classes c
           on l.class_id = c.id
      group by l.class_id, c.name, l.teacher_id, l.name
     ) l
group by teacher, name, weekday_hours;
```